# Unable to cross compile postgresql 12.2 for ARM

Tags: linux, postgresql, cross-compiling, autoconf

Hoping to get some help cross compiling postgresql from source for ARM. I am trying to build the library on `X86_64` `Ubuntu 18.04.4`.
I am using passing autoconf the following arguments:

```
CC=arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc CXX=arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ AR=arm-linux-gnueabihf-ar RANLIB=arm-linux-gnueabihf-ranlib ../configure --host=arm-linux-gnueabihf --without-readline --without-zlib
```

When I run configure with the above arguments with postgresql release `9.6.2`, it succeeds and I am able to build the library properly.
However, I would like to use the latest release, which is currently V `12.2`.

When I run the above command with V `12.2`, I get the following error message:

```
// a bunch of successfull output from autoconf before error message...
checking for /dev/urandom... configure: error: cannot check for file existence when cross compiling
```

Any ideas how to fix this? Is this a bug in their autoconf, or am I doing something wrong on my side?

Comment: Maybe you can try ` --without-random`

Comment: It doesn't seem to be an options. When I set the flag:
`configure: WARNING: unrecognized options: --without-random`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to `configure.in`, you should be able to override the check:

```sh
./configure USE_DEV_URANDOM=1 ...
```

Then PostgreSQL will be built to use `/dev/urandom` without checking for the file's existence on the build host.